# store strings with the stosw command - ASM

Tags: assembly

My Assembly Code to store a word at the addresses starting at 8C0A2 (40h Words in total)

Result form the code is that register CX is 0000h (as excpected) and DI ist 0082h (as excpected).

Inspecting the extrasegment ES at the gven addresses shows me that it is NOT set to the word AFFEh and i do not know why!

```
.186
.model  small
.stack  100h

.data
count   dw  0040h       ; write 40 times the string
muster  dw  0AFFEh      ; AFFEh to the Extrasegment with the
insert  dw  8C0Ah       ; address 8C0Ah

.code
start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax

    mov es, insert

    mov ax, muster

    mov cx, count

    mov di, 2       

    rep stosw       

    mov ah, 4Ch     
    int 21h
    end start
```

Comment: How are you reading the data to check the result?

Comment: It might not be affecting the result in this particular case, but you should really clear or set [the direction flag](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direction_flag) explictly (with `CLD` / `STD`) before any string instruction.

Comment: Your instruction is `mov es, insert`, and `insert` is 8C0Ah. I wouldn't expect ES to then contain AFFEh. It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: @ughoavgfhw i can check the result inside a debug envirnonment
@Micheal thx for the hint, i will set or clear the flag in future programms
@JimMischel the `stosw` stores a string from 'ax' to the memory with the address 'ES:DI'

Comment: You must have made some mistake running it or examining memory because I can't see anything wrong with it and in fact it [works for me in dosbox](http://i39.tinypic.com/1j156c.png).

Comment: "count   dw  0040h       ; write 40 times the string"
This is 4 x16 = 64 times. 40decimal in hex is 28h

Comment: what debugging environment are you using? This maybe relevant as it does not seem to be anything wrong with the code.

Comment: I *know* what `stosw` does. What I don't understand is what you're trying to do. Your code stores the value of AX (which is AFFEh) 64 times starting at ES:DI (8C0A:0002). Is that really what you want? What do you *want* the destination address to be? Also, when done, the word pointed to by ES:DI will not contain AFFEh, because the DI register has been incremented to the next word.

Comment: @Jester I did realy a mistake at axamining the data inside the extrasegment, the code works properly! thx for your help!

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly you are trying to do. The reason why word pointed to by `es` doesn't contain `0AFFEh` is `mov di, 2` - pattern inserting starts at `(es+2)`, and then goes on on to higher addresses.

Answer (score 0):

mov es,INSERT may be invalid, and you may need to point with bp to get the hex values

mov ax,DATA
mov ds,ax
mov bp,INSERT
mov es,[bp]
mov bp,MUSTER
mov ax,[bp]
mov bp,COUNT
mov cx,[bp]
mov di,2
rep stosw

DATA
COUNT
dw 40
MUSTER
dw AFFE
INSERT
dw 8C0A

all I get is a line of scores and squiggles.../~/~/~/~, which is AFFE the hex contents of ax

Usually losb/losw is used with stosw, this loads up al/ax

==========================

If this does work

```
   mov es, insert

   mov ax, muster

   mov cx, count
```

then all you are doing is loading es with the memory address of INSERT etc, not their contents

"Inspecting the extrasegment ES at the gven addresses shows me that it is NOT set to the word AFFE"

ES has 8C0A which is "INSERT"